# How to validate the phone no?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC and I want to validate the phone No

I wrote this class:

```
public class StudentValidator : AbstractValidator<graduandModel>
{
    public StudentValidator(ILocalizationService localizationService)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.phone).NotEmpty().WithMessage(localizationService.GetResource("Hire.HireItem.Fields.phone.Required"));
    }
}
```

How can I validate the phone number inside this class?

Can I use the following?

```
RuleFor(x => x.phone).SetValidator(....)
```

If so how can I use it??

Comment: A phone number from what country/countries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using [DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in your model?

Something like this:

```
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone Number")]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

Another solution would be the use of regular expressions:

```
[DisplayName("Phone number")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone number is required")]
[RegularExpression(@"((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid phone number")]
```

Comment: It won't work if you need to perform the validation on phone numbers from different countries.

Comment: You're right, in that case I would create my own class deriving from [RegularExpressionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx) and add some logic inside...

Answer (score 9):

the code sample below uses fluent validation for phone number validation

```
  class StudentCommandValidation :  AbstractValidator<StudentCommand>
{
    public StudentCommandValidation()
    {
        RuleFor(p => p.PhoneNumber)
       .NotEmpty()
       .NotNull().WithMessage("Phone Number is required.")
       .MinimumLength(10).WithMessage("PhoneNumber must not be less than 10 characters.")
       .MaximumLength(20).WithMessage("PhoneNumber must not exceed 50 characters.")
       .Matches(new Regex(@"((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}")).WithMessage("PhoneNumber not valid");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need regular expression.

Try this examples

[Regex Library](http://regexlib.com/%28A%284RYQ9h0Sbzr1tQFgCQt5HxrVEczRWMbgsbgLA1DaGOrMThPaeieWDZjlV748xdHuAtr75klQI5ZNxqqBWiCe98VhGt6i21J1HPZqtT3dZUKKvBjSICuAbhIhpQQz0wBcBic8EKKsY438DuouIwnB79_Jzo-Zh7zX6C3pz3gRFKafqzOSSLLUFqKE1ealINdG0%29%29/Search.aspx?k=&c=7&m=-1&ps=100)

and then you can use regex pattern in data anotations like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid phone number.")]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```